# I implemented Admobs and i can see eCPM, does that include also click earnings?

Tags: android, admob

When one implements an eCPM (cost per 1000) what happens when users click on ads, does the click get counted too or just the views ?

This question is for someone who has implemented an eCPM with Google Admobs.

Comment: Has nothing to do with programming, right?

Comment: yes, nothing with programing

Comment: In that case SO is bad place for that question.

Comment: do i have to remove it ?